# Is it possible to rotate a div on x,y,z axises?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know if that's possible but I don't know anything about this, so I decided to ask.
Is it possible to rotate a `div` on `x,y,z` axises using JavaScript libraries like jQuery or something like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can position via x and y (`left` and `top` properties in CSS).

You will need to have `position: absolute` or something other than static.

You may also change the z-order (stacking height). Also works in conjunction with something besides `position: static` (which is default).

However, with CSS3 you can rotate a div.

```
#my-div {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

Comment: this just rotate the div on Y axis, what about X,Z axis ?

Comment: You mean rotate into the page? Like skewing it? Might need to use Canvas for that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery addon to rotate (using the transform described in the other answer), but it doesn't work for IE.

If you are interested, check it out [here](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/08/07/jquery-animate-css-rotate-scale.html).

If you want to rotate an image, [this plugin](http://wilq32.googlepages.com/wilq32.rollimage222) will work for all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, no.  There is nothing I know which can achieve that for the time being.  To simulate a 3D rotation, the closest approach is to do it via some javascript canvas manipulation libraries.  I happened to find a [Javascript 3D renderer](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas3dtexture_0.2/) the other day.  Check it out if you're interested.  However, you should know that even with the [Canvas 3d JS Library](http://www.c3dl.org/) available, we won't be able to make a div (outside the canvas) to rotate in 3D.

Answer (score 0):

this jQuery plugin works for images, you could use it with divs

[link](http://wilq32.googlepages.com/wilq32.rollimage222)

Comment: how to rotate the div on X-axis ??